Uniqueness of solution to Dirichlet problem for heat equation in unbounded domains
Problem: Let $(M,g)$ be a stochastically complete Riemannian manifold and $\Omega \subset M$ a smooth unbounded domain. Denote by $u$ the (unique) bounded solution to the Cauchy problem
$\begin{cases} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\Delta \right)u=0 & \text{in}\ (0,+\infty)\times M\\ u(0,\cdot)=\chi_{\Omega} & \text{on}\ M, \end{cases}$
where $\chi_\Omega$ denotes the characteristic function of $\Omega$ in $M$. Consider the problem
$\begin{cases} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\Delta \right)v=0 & \text{in}\ (0,+\infty)\times \Omega\\ v(0,\cdot)=0 & \text{on}\ \Omega \\ v=0 & \text{on}\ (0,+\infty)\times \partial \Omega.\end{cases}$
Question 1: Is it true that $v\equiv 0$ is the only solution to the above Dirichlet boundary value problem?
Question 2: If we additionally suppose that $u(t,y)\equiv c\in (0,+\infty)$ on $(0,+\infty)\times \partial \Omega$ and we denote by $w$ the solution to
$\begin{cases} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\Delta \right)w=0 & \text{in}\ (0,+\infty)\times \Omega\\ w(0,\cdot)=1 & \text{on}\ \Omega \\ w=0 & \text{on}\ (0,+\infty)\times \partial \Omega,\end{cases}$
is it true that $U:= c^{-1} u -1\geq w$ in $(0,+\infty)\times \Omega$?

Do we really have unique solution? Is it part of the conclusion of stochastic completeness?

Yes, i forgot "the (unique) bounded solution". For instance, see Theorem 6.2 in "Analytic and Geometric Background of recurrence and non-explosion of the Brownian motion on Riemannian manifolds" by Grigor'yan.
